# What if anything is the significance of the gift given to Mirabel at the end of the film?

Tags: encanto

At the very end of Encanto, Mirabel is given a gift by the family:

> A magic doorknob

What, if anything, was the significance of that given the door symbolism earlier on in the film?

Comment: I've seen plenty of web-chatter that suggests that it shows that she has the same miraculous power as her Grandmother. So rather than getting no gift, she has the power to be a future source of gifts.

Comment: @Valorum I must have seen the exact same web chatter as well — it's what motivated me to ask here.

Comment: The novelisation isn't much help. Some waffle about family and the importance of blah.

Answer (score 5):

The film appears to be intentionally slightly ambiguous, but here's one theory based on what we see in the film.

**The magic is tied to family acceptance**

We see multiple times in the film that the strength of the magic is tied directly to the family relationships. The less accepted someone feels, the weaker both their personal magic, and the magic of the whole family. We see that Bruno's magic fades when he leaves the family, the cracks start to appear when Mirabel feels rejected, Louisa's magic fades as she takes on too much stress, and the Encanto is destroyed when Abuela and Mirabel argue. Conversely, the magic strengthens when Isabela feels truly accepted by Mirabel.

**The doors are therefore symbolic of the family's acceptance**

The doors are clearly part of receiving a Gift, and we've just seen that the Gift is tied to being accepted by the family. The doors are given to each child as they come of age - they have their names and faces on, and are unique to that person. As Bruno and Lousia feel more rejected by their family, their doors start to fade too. Mirabel's problems with not feeling part of the family begin at the point of not receiving her door:

> Always walking alone
> Always wanting for more
> Like I'm still at that door longing to shine
> Like all of you shine

Having a (working) door is therefore part of feeling accepted by the family.

**The door handle is symbolic of the family's acceptance of Mirabel**

Mirabel never felt part of the family because she never got a door. By giving her a door - and the front door, no less - the family are clearly demonstrating that they truly accept her.

> You're the real gift, kid.

I would be tempted to argue that it is this acceptance that restores the family's magic. That is to say, it isn't the doorknob that's magic, it's the sentiment behind the doorknob that is magic. But that said, I think part of the beauty of the film is that it isn't explained, leaving you to wonder.

Comment: In the novelisation she gets a bedroom with a magical door made by the whole family.